# Which (free) software will enable me to transfer video off my Sony Handycam to my PC?

Tags: windows-7, camcorder

Just dug out my old Sony Handycam (DCR-HC28) and found some old tapes.

I don't have any of the original software, and from a quick Googling session it may cost me $100 to buy it.

Is there a free alternative? I have a firewire cable all set, just need to find some software.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a MiniDV camcorder connected through FireWire, any standard video editor should be able to rip the footage; you don't need any specialized Sony software. Windows Live Movie Maker should be able to capture the video from the device, assuming it shows up in Device Manager without any extra drivers.

You can consult [this article](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/24/windows-7-rc-acquisition-from-dv-camera/) for some more information.

Comment: I actually had that camera for a short while and this is the way I transfered videos.